# Django my flash messages don't work

Tags: python, django, flash

I think it's something wrong with my settings, when I use flash in login action I cant see it in the index template, but when I use flash in "my" action I see duplicated of the message

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'bookmarks',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

view:

```
def login(request):
...
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        auth.login(request, user)
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'cant see it')

        return redirect(reverse('bookmarks:index'))
...


def my(request):
...
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'this is twice')

    return render(request, 'bookmarks/my.html', {
        'bookmarks': bookmarks
    })
```

and my index.html

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

//**edit**
maybe something with routing?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
...
    url(r'^my/$', views.my, name = 'my'),
...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

These flash messages only get shown when you render a page.

That's why you see two messages:

1. You login successfully and set a message
2. You redirect to your index view, the messages framework remembers the message
3. Your index view renders the page and shows both messages

Comment: No, I just login, next I go to index page and I dont see flash message. My secound behavior is: I go to "my" action then I go to index page and I see label "this is twice" duplicated